# behringer xenyx 302usb with C1, volume is too low

Tags: behringer

I have a behringer xenyx 302usb connected with XLR to a behringer c1.

With this setup i need to turn the volume and the gain knobs to the max to get a decent waveform when recorded. at normal gain and volume levels the recorded audio is nearly inaudible.

xenyx 302usb manual says it has phantom power on by default. but i guess it doesn't seem to be working? or am i missing something.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately xenyx 302usb doesn't provide adequate phantom power for a condenser mic. It just provides 15V where a condenser mic requires 48V.

The only solution is to get a preamp with 48V phantom power and connect its output to a line input on xenyx.

There is also no technical specifications sheet on its product page. I actually never heard of any use of 15V phantom power. Looks like false advertisement by the company. You can even return the item because it doesn't do what it says and get a proper device with 48V phantom power.

Before that you may also try if connecting the unit with a power adapter makes any difference.

Comment: Ouch. The ghost of phantom power... It's perfectly possible to get full phantom from a USB-only interface, so there's no excuse for the manufacturer to cheapskate

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess i'll try again with the power adapter but then i'm gonna have to use unbalanced cables to connect it to the computer. This is frustrating and fake marketing :/

Comment: tried with the AC adapter and the USB and connected to the computer. It didn't work either. This mixer i bought is useless. :(